# Is there a phrase for eggcorn but instead of homophones it's synonyms?

Tags: single-word-requests

Pretty straightforward question, I hope. For anyone who doesn't know:

"In eggcorns, people replace the right word with a different word that sounds the same—a homophone—that makes logical sense in the phrase." - [Source](https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/spoonerisms-mondegreens-eggcorns-and-malapropisms)

Is there a phrase to describe this phenomenon but instead of a homophone being used in slight error when reciting an idiom, it's a synonym? I do this all the time but can only think of one example because it happened today.

The phrase "big ticket items" refers to large, major, expensive 'purchases.' When writing this phrase down, I instead wrote "big ticket purchases." The phrase is right, but slightly off, because a synonym is used, so the meaning is unchanged, but the original wording is wrong. Is there a word for this phenomenon?

Comment: "[Big ticket purchase](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/big-ticket-purchase)" does have some currency though.

Comment: Old joke: A grizzled pastor spoke a word on the serious matter of the sermon for the young, guest preacher. "You'll have to speak loudly, son. The *agnostics* in here are terrible." That said, you might want to see if *mumpsimus* will fit your bill.

Comment: @rajah9 That's called a _malapropism_ which is a kind of solecism. The OP seems to be talking of doing something that results in correct semantics but just happens to use a different term than usual.

Comment: *unidiomatic*  ..

Comment: @Tinfoil Hat thank you! unidiomatic captures it, though somewhat indirectly and too broadly honestly. I'm thinking of unidiomatic idiomatic speech by native speakers of that language, where the phrase is synonymous  only slightly off, not significantly unidiomatic. Unidiomatic seems to imply it's being spoken not as a native language. Also the definition of not conforming to accepted/established idiom feels broad; eggcorn is unidiomatic, no? unidiomatic synonymous idioms. not just a different term, but a synonym. doesn't have to be an established term, what would y'all call it?

Comment: [***idionym***](http://www1.biologie.uni-hamburg.de/b-online/library/tennessee/nom-onyms.htm) appears to be taken — *A homonym(s) created by misinterpretation or misidentification of specimens of different taxa* — but maybe you could make it work.